# how to add serial no in quotation, sales order and invoice

Tags: odoo

Is it possible to add extra field in quotation, sales order and invoice. This field should be first field and it should appear like sl.no and each product we enter should get 1, 2, 3..so on.

I can say it is applying item numbers (not code) in quotation, sales order and Invoice. This is really important requirement in Indian accountancy.

Thanks for your reply !!

Answer (score 0):

There is already a field called 'sequence' in sale order line and invoice line.This field have some specialties. After adding this field you can drag and drop the lines with in the list.